# Where can I download a windows binary of Windres (part of Binutils)?

Tags: windows

Can't find any prebuilt binaries for Windows. Does anybody know a place where I can get them?

Comment: For the record, Windres is a resource compiler. Didn't expect this to get any close votes. Still off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes with [MinGW](http://mingw.org/). You can download the installer [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20101030/mingw-get-inst-20101030.exe/download).

Comment: It also comes with [Free Pascal Compiler](http://www.freepascal.org/download.var), and I feel like an idiot for not noticing because I only needed windres to compile an FPC program.