# How can i set what version of a product I'm in Eclipse?

Tags: windows, linux, mingw, versioning, eclipse-cdt

I've created, debugged, and revised a project that I've been working on, but now I want to be able to specify what version of the binary I'm on.  I'm using Eclispe-CDT with MinGW to make this project on my local system, so there is no versioning software involved.  Does anyone know how to specify this for both Windows and Linux platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the idea is to produce a [COFF file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) with the relevant information.

That is done by adding a step to the build, using **[windres](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/windres.html)** ([found also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4768007/6309)).
See [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/42691/138775/#msg_138775) as an example.

> you could add `windres` via the project `properties/Builders` as an additional builder and add the generated object file in the C/C++ Build/GCC C++ `Linker/Miscellaneous/Other Objects`.
>
> Then you 
>   - a) could do a clean build if the resource is changed or 
>   - b) could change the build options (if you have patience) to change to do a clean build every time you save the project.

On Unix, this doesn't seem to be supported in a similar fashion.